# Woodbury matrix identity with scalars

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have the following recurrence relation:
$$ \alpha \times A_{t+1} = \beta \times A_{t} + uu^{T}$$
where $A = n \times n, u = n \times 1 $ and $\alpha , \beta$ are scalars.
I would like to apply the [Woodbury Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) to this relation if possible:

$$ (A + UCV)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U)^{-1} VA^{-1}$$
My first guess was to rearrange the rhs to make it look like the lhs of the Woodbury identity, something like:

$$ \frac{\alpha}{\beta} A_{t+1} = A_{t} + \frac{uu^{T}}{\beta} $$

My idea was to make $\beta$ the $1 \times 1$ C-Matrix from the Woodbury identity, so far this approach is incorrect. In the end  I would like to find $ (A_{t+1})^{-1} $.

Every hint or suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SE! It's not clear what your question is. Consider separating clearly (A) your problem setup (B) what you've done (C) what is your question.

Comment: @dohmatob Note that the poster says "In the end  I would like to find $ (A_{t+1})^{-1} $".

Comment: Ah, ok I didn't see that. I've removed my comment and upvoted the question!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are non-zero. Note that 
$$
A_{t+1}^{-1} = \left(\frac1{\alpha}\cdot (\beta A_t + uu^T)\right)^{-1} = \alpha (\beta A_t + uu^T)^{-1}.
$$
With the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) (which is the same as applying the Woodbury formula in the case that $U^T,V$ are column vectors), we have
$$
\begin{align}
(\beta A_t + uu^T)^{-1} &= (\beta A_t + uu^T)^{-1} 
\\ & = (\beta A_t)^{-1} + \frac{(\beta A_t)^{-1}uu^T (\beta A_t)^{-1}}{1 + u^T (\beta A_t)^{-1}u}
\\ & =
\beta^{-1}A_t^{-1} + \frac{\beta^{-2} A_t^{-1}uu^T  A_t^{-1}}{1 + \beta^{-1} u^T A_t^{-1}u}
\\ & = 
\beta^{-1}A_t^{-1} + \beta^{-1}\frac{A_t^{-1}uu^T  A_t^{-1}}{\beta + u^T A_t^{-1}u}
= 
\beta^{-1}\left[
A_t^{-1} + \frac{A_t^{-1}uu^T  A_t^{-1}}{\beta + u^T A_t^{-1}u}
\right].
\end{align}
$$

Comment: many thanks, helped me to solve it